# Make tabu fill width with equal horizontal padding without X columns

Tags: tabu

Is there a way to have a `tabu` in LaTeX that fills to a certain with (as in with `\begin{tabu} to \textwidth}`, but without the `X` column type? I don't want the columns to all be the same width, but I want the horizontal paddings around each column to be the same. Here's a table with sample text that I would want to be spaced out more so that there isn't a ton of space on the left and right: [image: table without what I want]

Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, tabu}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\setlength{\tabulinesep}{4pt}

\begin{document}
    \[\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {M*3{|M}}
    p=p_0+\rho gh&\rho=\frac{m}{V}&v_\text{max}=\omega A&p+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2+\rho gh=\text{constant}
    \end{tabu}\]
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I am willing to use tabular environments that aren't `tabu`.

Comment: You should be aware of https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu.

Comment: I don't use `tabu`, but can't you add extra `X` columns just for the spacing?

Comment: Actually I just tried `\begin{tabu} spread \textwidth {XMX*3{|XMX}}` and it does work completely fine, I just don't like the fact that I have to space every column with `&&&`. If there aren't any other options though, I can stick with that

Comment: Why not use tabular* with @extracolsep{\fill} instead?